# Why cls() in a classmethod does not provide argument hints the way that directly calling the class constructor does?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, vscode-python, python-datamodel

I'm trying to make a subclass with a `@classmethod` that would take as arguments an instance of its superclass and kwargs for its other fields. The goal is to be able to take an object of the general class and "extend" it into an object of the subclass.
Doing this, I've noticed a behavior of VSCode which I don't understand: When writing a `@classmethod`, the `cls` argument does not provide the argument hinting that calling the class constructor directly does.

Consider the following example:

```python
import dataclasses
from typing import Self

@dataclasses.dataclass(kw_only=True)
class A:
    x: int

@dataclasses.dataclass(kw_only=True)
class B(A):
    y: int

    @classmethod
    def from_a_1(cls, a: A, y: int) -> Self:
        return cls(x=a.x, y=y) # cls() does not show argument hints

    @classmethod
    def from_a_2(cls, a: A, y: int) -> 'B':
        return B(x=a.x, y=y) #  B() does show hints just fine

a = A(x=1)
b_1 = B.from_a_1(a=a, y=2)
b_2 = B.from_a_2(a=a, y=2)
```

As the image on the left shows, for a direct class call `B()` it is possible to *Trigger Parameter Hints*, and also keyword arguments are shown in *Trigger Suggest*. The image on the right shows that the other variant, calling `cls()` makes *Trigger Parameter Hints* totally unavailable, and it does not show keyword arguments in *Trigger Suggest*.

[image: argument hint show for direct class call][image: argument hint not shown for call using cls]

This prompted me to think that perhaps I don't have a good understanding of using classmethods, or that something about this confuses VSCode. **What is the difference between those two different ways of doing (in this case) the same thing?**

Furthermore, **are `b_1` and `b_2` really the same thing / do those 2 approaches lead to same results?**

Also to address the possible [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), **what is the proper/reasonable/pythonic way to (take object of superclass) -> (make it into an object of subclass and fill the extra fields)?**

Comment: Here's the question to ask: what is the *static* type of `cls`? There's no type hint, and *statically* there's no connection between the definition of `from_a_1` and how you *assume* it will be called at runtime. (Further, the fact that `from_a_1` will be bound to an instance of `classmethod` rather than the function defined by the `def` statement isn't something you can know statically; it requires an assumption about what `classmethod` is bound to and will do at runtime.)

Comment: if you have another class that extends B, `class C(B): pass`, then you can call `C.from_a_1(a, y)` and `cls` will be `C`, not `B`